# Rejecting a particular frequency band using DWT

Tags: matlab

My problem is as follows: I decompose the 4th level **detail** coefficient of an ECG signal further up to the fourth level and I want to reject the approx. coeff. at this level, which corresponds to the powerline interference. I reject this by using upcoef() with 'd' and then specifying only the detail coefficient. Then I want to keep on using idwt() to get back at the previous level , but this is not being possible because of the length mismatch of the new reconstucted detail coeffs. and the original approx. coeffs.
I would like to know if at all it is possible (in MATLAB) to reject a frequency band corresponding to the further decomposition of the **detail** coefficient, because when you go back up, the reconstructed coefficient lengths are different because of the inherent convolution operation.

I am posting my code below:

```
[C1, L1]=wavedec(detrendedecg, 4, 'db8');
[cd4]=detcoef(C1,L1,[4]);

[aa1,dd1]=dwt(cd4, 'db8');
[aa2,dd2]=dwt(dd1, 'db8');
[aa3,dd3]=dwt(dd2, 'db8');
[aa4,dd4]=dwt(dd3, 'db8');
newdd3=idwt([],dd4,'db8');

newdd2=idwt([aa3],[newdd3],'db8');
newdd1=idwt([aa2],[newdd2],'db8');
newcd4=idwt([aa1],[newdd1],'db8');
```

the original signal is `detrendedecg`. It is decomposed upto level 4 to get `cd4` as detail coefficient. `cd4` is decomposed again up to 4 levels to obtain `dd4`  as the detail coefficient at level 4. I want to reject the approx coefficient at this level, i.e., `aa4`. But this code doesn't help. It gives a matrix dimension mismatch error on the third line from thee end. What do I do now?

Comment: What are you expecting us to do? Write the code and post it here? Please specify where exactly problem lies - is it that you don't know how to synthesise your signal, MATLAB crashes, you lack theory, results are wrong, ... ?

Comment: @jojek As I already mentioned, I am not able to recover the original signal back. More specifically, when I decompose the 4th level detail coefficient further upto the fourth level, I want to reject the approx. coeff. which corresponds to the powerline interference. I reject this by using upcoef() with 'd'  and then specifying only the detail coefficient. Then I want to keep on using idwt() to get back at the previous level , but this is not being possible b'coz of diff. lengths of detail coeff. and approx. coeffs. on reconst. every time.

Comment: [C1, L1]=wavedec(detrendedecg, 4, 'db8');
[cd4]=detcoef(C1,L1,[4]);
[aa1,dd1]=dwt(cd4, 'db8');
 [aa2,dd2]=dwt(dd1, 'db8');
 [aa3,dd3]=dwt(dd2, 'db8');
[aa4,dd4]=dwt(dd3, 'db8');
newdd3=idwt([],dd4,'db8');
newdd2=idwt([aa3],[newdd3],'db8');
newdd1=idwt([aa2],[newdd2],'db8');
newcd4=idwt([aa1],[newdd1],'db8');

Comment: Please post any code and further explanation in edited question not in the comment.

Comment: I have posted the edited question along with the code.